# Change code color for HTML file for Angular in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I would like to change the color scheme of the HTML file of the Angular Components in VS Code to match the following:
[What I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZriGa.png)
As you can see in this image the TypeScript functions and variables have different colors inside the quotation marks.
This is what I currently have
[What I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZhC7.png)

All my internet browsing is telling me to change the setting.json file, but I ended up just changing the color of the whole strings themselves like this:
[What I've changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA7ht.png)
Here's the code that I've tried so far

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "[Default Dark Modern]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "string, punctuation.definition.string.begin, punctuation.definition.string.end",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#a9c45e",
                        "fontStyle": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Also, tried to use the vscode-angular-html extension as recommended in my internet browsing but I don't know how to use it and there are no good instructions to set it up correctly. I did try to add different hex colors in the HTML section of the extension settings but they didn't change the actual code color.

This is the setting.json file code structure after I ran the **vscode-angular-html: Set legacy color customization** command:

```
{
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "html-template.tag.html",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#569CD6"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.tag.custom",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#569CD6"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attribute.doctype",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#4EC9B0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.exclamation.doctype",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.doctype",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.entities.ampersand",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.entities.semicolon",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.generic",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#4EC9B0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.events",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#4EC9B0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "punctuation.separator.key-value.html-template.ng",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.style.language.identifier",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.script.language.identifier",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.link.myme-type",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.aria-attribute.prefix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#569CD6"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.aria-attribute.suffix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#4EC9B0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.data-attribute.prefix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.data-attribute.suffix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#4EC9B0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.interpolation.begin",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.interpolation.end",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.expression.operator.logical",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.expression.operator.compound",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.expression.operator.bitwise",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.expression.operator.comparison",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.expression.operator.relational",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.expression.operator.arithmetic",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.expression.operator.navigator",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "entity.name.tag.html.ng",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.animationtrigger.prefix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.animationtrigger.variable",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "punctuation.definition.ng-binding-name.begin.html",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "punctuation.definition.ng-binding-name.end.html",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.event-handler",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.input-binding.animationTrigger.prefix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.input-binding.first-level",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.input-binding.second-level",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.input-binding.third-level",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.prefix.let",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#569CD6"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.prefix.ref",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.suffix.name",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#4EC9B0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.suffix.rxjs",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.prefix.sugar",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.suffix.sugar",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.template.prefix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.template.variable",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.control-flow.prefix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.control-flow.keyword",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "entity.name.tag.html.primeng",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.tag.svg",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#569CD6"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.svg.path.commands",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.tag.colon",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.tag.suffix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.colon",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.attributes.suffix",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.xmlStylesheet.language.identifier",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#B5CEA8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.exclamation.dtd",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#C586C0"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.dtd",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.qualifier.dtd",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#569CD6"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "html-template.ng.occurrence.dtd",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D16969"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "vscode-angular-html.angularBindingAttributeDelimiter": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularAndAngularMaterialElementTags": "#D7BA7D",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularAnimationTriggerPrefix": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularAnimationTriggerVariableName": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularEventHandlerName": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularExpression": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularExpressionOperatorsAndNavigatorsColor": "#C586C0",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularOneWayBindingAnimationTriggerDecorator": "#D7BA7D",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularOneWayBindingFirstLevelDepth": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularOneWayBindingSecondLevelDepth": "#C586C0",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularOneWayBindingThirdLevelDepth": "#D7BA7D",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularPrefixedAttributesLetPrefix": "#569CD6",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularPrefixedAttributesRefPrefix": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularPrefixedAttributesRxjsSuffix": "#D7BA7D",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularPrefixedAttributesVariableName": "#4EC9B0",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularSyntaxSugarAttributesName": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularSyntaxSugarAttributesPrefix": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularTemplateVariableName": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.angularTemplateVariablePrefix": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.controlFlowPrefix": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.controlFlowKeyword": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.dtdDoctypeElement": "#D7BA7D",
  "vscode-angular-html.dtdDoctypeExclamation": "#C586C0",
  "vscode-angular-html.dtdDoctypeQualifier": "#569CD6",
  "vscode-angular-html.dtdDoctypeQuantifier": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlAttributeValueSeparator": "#D7BA7D",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlCustomTags": "#569CD6",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlDoctypeAttributes": "#4EC9B0",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlDoctypeElement": "#D7BA7D",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlDoctypeExclamation": "#C586C0",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlEntitiesAmpersand": "#C586C0",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlEntitiesSemicolon": "#C586C0",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlEventsAttributes": "#4EC9B0",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlGenericAttributesFollowedByParameter": "#4EC9B0",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlScriptAttributesLanguageIdentifier": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlLinkAttributesMimeType": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlStyleAttributesLanguageIdentifier": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.htmlTags": "#569CD6",
  "vscode-angular-html.primeNgElementTags": "#D7BA7D",
  "vscode-angular-html.svgDAttributePathCommands": "#C586C0",
  "vscode-angular-html.svgTags": "#569CD6",
  "vscode-angular-html.ariaAttributePrefix": "#569CD6",
  "vscode-angular-html.ariaAttributeSuffix": "#4EC9B0",
  "vscode-angular-html.dataAttributePrefix": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.dataAttributeSuffix": "#4EC9B0",
  "vscode-angular-html.xmlAttributeNamespaceDivider": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.xmlAttributeNamespaceSuffix": "#C586C0",
  "vscode-angular-html.xmlStylesheetAttributesLanguageIdentifier": "#B5CEA8",
  "vscode-angular-html.xmlTagNamespaceDivider": "#D16969",
  "vscode-angular-html.xmlTagNamespaceSuffix": "#C586C0",
  "vscode-angular-html.colorCustomizations": true,
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "workbench.settings.applyToAllProfiles": [
    "vscode-angular-html.angularBindingAttributeDelimiter"
  ],
  "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
}
```

Comment: fyi: extension docs are in https://github.com/ghaschel/vscode-angular-html/tree/master/docs

Comment: @starball Hi...thanks for the comment. I went back to the suggested docs in github and ran the vscode-angular-html: Set legacy color customization command, and I checked the setting.json code. Indeed it did change it but I didn't see the effect in html file. I edited the original post to add the setting.json script. Could you take a look and see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @JoseRoman I am the author of vscode-angular-html. What you said happened seems unusual. Feel free to open an issue for us to be able to track it down. This might be a theme request issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) extension in your VS Code. This service does exactly what you need and much more.

Comment: I have this extension installed but don't know how to set it up for Syntax Highlighting. I'm a quick study, I'm just having trouble setting this one up. Could you help?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? You should have Angular 13 or newer to make the Language Service work. Remove all the changes you made in VS Code settings. Remove also all other extensions you have added (at least the ones which try to manipulate the HTML highlighting). Angular Language Service should start highlighting the code without any additional settings. More information you may find here https://angular.io/guide/language-service

Comment: Thanks @wnvko. I deleted all the extensions in VS Code (Don't worry, I am a patient person) and added just the Angular Service Language. It automatically changed all the colors. The only thing I'm bugged about is that it doesn't give me errors in the HTML component when variables and functions are not defined in the TS Component. Would you happen to know what I need to tweak for that? Thank you for your patience too.

Comment: You are welcome @JoseRoman.
Actually I did not setup anything in language service. The only thing is to set strictTemplates to true in tsconfig as described here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template#configuring-compiler-options-for-the-angular-language-service
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yep...that was great. Also, I was creating the Apps with the --no-strict rule which also doesn't enforce the errors in the HTML page for functions, variables, etc. Now I'm just creating them without that rule and it automatically adds the script to the tsconfig.json file. I like those guardrails in place, from a t/shooting perspective they are time-savers.